# How do I get gcc to run on CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, gcc, python3

I'm running CentOS 7.  I want to re-build Python with a new openssl package I just installed but I can't seem to get it to compile.  I ran this

```
sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
```

which ran successfully.  But when I run ./configure when building Python, I run into problems ...

```
(venv) [rails@server Python-3.7.0]$ ./configure
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for python3.7... python3.7
checking for --enable-universalsdk... no
checking for --with-universal-archs... no
checking MACHDEP... checking for --without-gcc... no
checking for --with-icc... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/tmp/Python-3.7.0':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

What else do I need to do build Python 3?

**Edit:** Info as requested by comments...

```
(venv) [rails@server Python-3.7.0]$ findmnt --target /tmp/Python-3.7.0
TARGET SOURCE                             FSTYPE OPTIONS
/      /dev/simfs[/home/vz/private/20428] simfs  rw,relatime
```

Comment: Edit question to show -- What are the mount options of the current working directory? (`findmnt --target /tmp/Python-3.7.0`)

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I started with a fresh CentOS 7 install, ran `yum update`, rebooted, downloaded https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.7/Python-3.7.7.tgz, `tar -xf Python-3.7.7.tgz`, `cd Python-3.7.7`, `./configure` (reproduced error), `yum groupinstall "Development Tools"`, `./configure` (success)

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor, added info per your request as an edit

Comment: @cherdt, it woudl appear I didn't install "Development Tools" successfully.  Reading back through the logs, yum can't find it.  I opened a separate question -- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/585275/where-do-i-get-development-tools-for-centos-7-when-trying-to-install-via-yum

Answer (score 0):

You should leave the virtual environment before you are trying to build Python as the venv heavily modifies your environment. Your prompt indicates that you inside a Python virtual environment.

When configure fails it usually writes concrete error message into a log file. Check that log file for the root cause.

Recent versions of CentOS 7 include dnf, and with that you can install build requirements simply with:

```
dnf builddep python3
```