# Where do I get "Development Tools" for CentOS 7 when trying to install via yum?

Tags: centos, yum, gcc, development

I'm running CentOS 7.  I want to install gcc (for the purposes of building Python 3 with the new openssl package I installed).  I was reading here -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19816275/no-acceptable-c-compiler-found-in-path-when-installing-python, that installing "Development Tools" was the truth and the light.  But I don't seem to be able to ...

```
(venv) [rails@server Python-3.7.0]$ sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
[sudo] password for rails: 
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.mi.incx.net
 * epel: mirror.us-midwest-1.nexcess.net
 * extras: mirror.cs.pitt.edu
 * updates: mirror.pit.teraswitch.com
Maybe run: yum groups mark install (see man yum)
No packages in any requested group available to install or update
```

Here's some extra info about my system if needed

```
(venv) [rails@server Python-3.7.0]$ uname -a
Linux server 2.6.32-042stab120.19 #1 SMP Mon Feb 20 20:05:53 MSK 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Edit:** Adding results as suggested by answer ...

```
[rails@server ~]$ sudo yum groups mark install "Development Tools"
[sudo] password for rails: 
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.ussg.iu.edu
 * epel: mirror.us-midwest-1.nexcess.net
 * extras: mirror.cs.uwp.edu
 * updates: mirror.pit.teraswitch.com
Marked install: Development Tools
[rails@server ~]$ sudo yum groups mark convert "Development Tools"
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.ussg.iu.edu
 * epel: mirror.us-midwest-1.nexcess.net
 * extras: mirror.cs.uwp.edu
 * updates: mirror.pit.teraswitch.com
Converted old style groups to objects.
[rails@server ~]$ sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.ussg.iu.edu
 * epel: mirror.us-midwest-1.nexcess.net
 * extras: mirror.cs.uwp.edu
 * updates: mirror.pit.teraswitch.com
Maybe run: yum groups mark install (see man yum)
No packages in any requested group available to install or update
```

**Edit 2** More output in response to comments from answers ...

```
[rails@server ~]$ sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools" --setopt=group_package_types=mandatory,default,optional
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.vcu.edu
 * epel: mirror.us-midwest-1.nexcess.net
 * extras: ftp.osuosl.org
 * updates: mirror.mi.incx.net
Maybe run: yum groups mark install (see man yum)
No packages in any requested group available to install or update
```

and this ...

```
[rails@server ~]$ sudo yum grouplist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.vcu.edu
 * epel: mirror.us-midwest-1.nexcess.net
 * extras: repo1.ash.innoscale.net
 * updates: mirror.mi.incx.net
Available Environment Groups:
   Minimal Install
   Compute Node
   Infrastructure Server
   File and Print Server
   Cinnamon Desktop
   MATE Desktop
   Basic Web Server
   Virtualization Host
   Server with GUI
   GNOME Desktop
   KDE Plasma Workspaces
   Development and Creative Workstation
Installed Groups:
   Console Internet Tools
   Development Tools
   Electronic Lab
   Legacy UNIX Compatibility
   Milkymist
   PostgreSQL Database Server 9.6 PGDG
   Security Tools
   System Administration Tools
Available Groups:
   Cinnamon
   Compatibility Libraries
   Educational Software
   Fedora Packager
   General Purpose Desktop
   Graphical Administration Tools
   Haskell
   LXQt Desktop
   MATE
   PostgreSQL Database Server 10 PGDG
   PostgreSQL Database Server 11 PGDG
   PostgreSQL Database Server 12 PGDG
   PostgreSQL Database Server 9.5 PGDG
   Scientific Support
   Smart Card Support
   System Management
   TurboGears application framework
   Xfce
Done
```

**Edit 3:** Output per second suggestion (repolist) ...

```
[rails@server ~]$ sudo yum repolist all
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.trouble-free.net
 * epel: mirror.us-midwest-1.nexcess.net
 * extras: mirror.pit.teraswitch.com
 * updates: mirrors.gigenet.com
repo id                                             repo name                                                                    status
C7.0.1406-base/x86_64                               CentOS-7.0.1406 - Base                                                       disabled
C7.0.1406-centosplus/x86_64                         CentOS-7.0.1406 - CentOSPlus                                                 disabled
C7.0.1406-extras/x86_64                             CentOS-7.0.1406 - Extras                                                     disabled
C7.0.1406-fasttrack/x86_64                          CentOS-7.0.1406 - Fasttrack                                                  disabled
C7.0.1406-updates/x86_64                            CentOS-7.0.1406 - Updates                                                    disabled
C7.1.1503-base/x86_64                               CentOS-7.1.1503 - Base                                                       disabled
C7.1.1503-centosplus/x86_64                         CentOS-7.1.1503 - CentOSPlus                                                 disabled
C7.1.1503-extras/x86_64                             CentOS-7.1.1503 - Extras                                                     disabled
C7.1.1503-fasttrack/x86_64                          CentOS-7.1.1503 - Fasttrack                                                  disabled
C7.1.1503-updates/x86_64                            CentOS-7.1.1503 - Updates                                                    disabled
C7.2.1511-base/x86_64                               CentOS-7.2.1511 - Base                                                       disabled
C7.2.1511-centosplus/x86_64                         CentOS-7.2.1511 - CentOSPlus                                                 disabled
C7.2.1511-extras/x86_64                             CentOS-7.2.1511 - Extras                                                     disabled
C7.2.1511-fasttrack/x86_64                          CentOS-7.2.1511 - Fasttrack                                                  disabled
C7.2.1511-updates/x86_64                            CentOS-7.2.1511 - Updates                                                    disabled
C7.3.1611-base/x86_64                               CentOS-7.3.1611 - Base                                                       disabled
C7.3.1611-centosplus/x86_64                         CentOS-7.3.1611 - CentOSPlus                                                 disabled
C7.3.1611-extras/x86_64                             CentOS-7.3.1611 - Extras                                                     disabled
C7.3.1611-fasttrack/x86_64                          CentOS-7.3.1611 - Fasttrack                                                  disabled
C7.3.1611-updates/x86_64                            CentOS-7.3.1611 - Updates                                                    disabled
C7.4.1708-base/x86_64                               CentOS-7.4.1708 - Base                                                       disabled
C7.4.1708-centosplus/x86_64                         CentOS-7.4.1708 - CentOSPlus                                                 disabled
C7.4.1708-extras/x86_64                             CentOS-7.4.1708 - Extras                                                     disabled
C7.4.1708-fasttrack/x86_64                          CentOS-7.4.1708 - Fasttrack                                                  disabled
C7.4.1708-updates/x86_64                            CentOS-7.4.1708 - Updates                                                    disabled
C7.5.1804-base/x86_64                               CentOS-7.5.1804 - Base                                                       disabled
C7.5.1804-centosplus/x86_64                         CentOS-7.5.1804 - CentOSPlus                                                 disabled
C7.5.1804-extras/x86_64                             CentOS-7.5.1804 - Extras                                                     disabled
C7.5.1804-fasttrack/x86_64                          CentOS-7.5.1804 - Fasttrack                                                  disabled
C7.5.1804-updates/x86_64                            CentOS-7.5.1804 - Updates                                                    disabled
C7.6.1810-base/x86_64                               CentOS-7.6.1810 - Base                                                       disabled
C7.6.1810-centosplus/x86_64                         CentOS-7.6.1810 - CentOSPlus                                                 disabled
C7.6.1810-extras/x86_64                             CentOS-7.6.1810 - Extras                                                     disabled
C7.6.1810-fasttrack/x86_64                          CentOS-7.6.1810 - Fasttrack                                                  disabled
C7.6.1810-updates/x86_64                            CentOS-7.6.1810 - Updates                                                    disabled
C7.7.1908-base/x86_64                               CentOS-7.7.1908 - Base                                                       disabled
C7.7.1908-centosplus/x86_64                         CentOS-7.7.1908 - CentOSPlus                                                 disabled
C7.7.1908-extras/x86_64                             CentOS-7.7.1908 - Extras                                                     disabled
C7.7.1908-fasttrack/x86_64                          CentOS-7.7.1908 - Fasttrack                                                  disabled
C7.7.1908-updates/x86_64                            CentOS-7.7.1908 - Updates                                                    disabled
base/7/x86_64                                       CentOS-7 - Base                                                              enabled: 10,070
base-debuginfo/x86_64                               CentOS-7 - Debuginfo                                                         disabled
base-source/7                                       CentOS-7 - Base Sources                                                      disabled
c7-media                                            CentOS-7 - Media                                                             disabled
centos-kernel/7/x86_64                              CentOS LTS Kernels for x86_64                                                disabled
centos-kernel-experimental/7/x86_64                 CentOS Experimental Kernels for x86_64                                       disabled
centosplus/7/x86_64                                 CentOS-7 - Plus                                                              disabled
centosplus-source/7                                 CentOS-7 - Plus Sources                                                      disabled
cr/7/x86_64                                         CentOS-7 - cr                                                                disabled
epel/x86_64                                         Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                               enabled: 13,266
epel-debuginfo/x86_64                               Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - Debug                       disabled
epel-source/x86_64                                  Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64 - Source                      disabled
epel-testing/x86_64                                 Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - Testing - x86_64                     disabled
epel-testing-debuginfo/x86_64                       Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - Testing - x86_64 - Debug             disabled
epel-testing-source/x86_64                          Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - Testing - x86_64 - Source            disabled
extras/7/x86_64                                     CentOS-7 - Extras                                                            enabled:    392
extras-source/7                                     CentOS-7 - Extras Sources                                                    disabled
fasttrack/7/x86_64                                  CentOS-7 - fasttrack                                                         disabled
google-chrome                                       google-chrome                                                                enabled:      3
pgdg-common/7/x86_64                                PostgreSQL common RPMs for RHEL/CentOS 7 - x86_64                            enabled:    288
pgdg-common-srpm-testing/7/x86_64                   PostgreSQL common testing SRPMs for RHEL/CentOS 7 - x86_64                   disabled
pgdg-common-testing/7/x86_64                        PostgreSQL common testing RPMs for RHEL/CentOS 7 - x86_64                    disabled
pgdg-source-common/7/x86_64                         PostgreSQL 12 for RHEL/CentOS 7 - x86_64 - Source                            disabled
pgdg10/7/x86_64                                     PostgreSQL 10 for RHEL/CentOS 7 - x86_64                                     enabled:    626
pgdg10-source/7/x86_64                              PostgreSQL 10 for RHEL/CentOS 7 - x86_64 - Source                            disabled
pgdg10-updates-debuginfo/7/x86_64                   PostgreSQL 10 for RHEL/CentOS 7 - x86_64 - Debuginfo                         disabled
pgdg11/7/x86_64                                     PostgreSQL 11 for RHEL/CentOS 7 - x86_64                                     enabled:    623
pgdg11-source/7/x86_64                              PostgreSQL 11 for RHEL/CentOS 7 - x86_64 - Source                            disabled
pgdg11-source-updates-testing/7/x86_64              PostgreSQL 11 for RHEL/CentOS 7 - x86_64 - Source update testing             disabled
pgdg11-updates-debuginfo/7/x86_64                   PostgreSQL 11 for RHEL/CentOS 7 - x86_64 - Debuginfo                         disabled
pgdg11-updates-testing/7/x86_64                     PostgreSQL 11 for RHEL/CentOS 7 - x86_64 - Updates testing                   disabled
pgdg11-updates-testing-debuginfo/7/x86_64           PostgreSQL 11 for RHEL/CentOS 7 - x86_64 - Debuginfo                         disabled
pgdg12/7/x86_64                                     PostgreSQL 12 for RHEL/CentOS 7 - x86_64                                     enabled:    317
pgdg12-source/7/x86_64                              PostgreSQL 12 for RHEL/CentOS 7 - x86_64 - Source                            disabled
pgdg12-source-updates-testing/7/x86_64              PostgreSQL 12 for RHEL/CentOS 7 - x86_64 - Source update testing             disabled
pgdg12-updates-debuginfo/7/x86_64                   PostgreSQL 12 for RHEL/CentOS 7 - x86_64 - Debuginfo                         disabled
pgdg12-updates-testing/7/x86_64                     PostgreSQL 12 for RHEL/CentOS 7 - x86_64 - Updates testing                   disabled
pgdg12-updates-testing-debuginfo/7/x86_64           PostgreSQL 12 for RHEL/CentOS 7 - x86_64 - Debuginfo                         disabled
pgdg13-source-updates-testing/7/x86_64              PostgreSQL 13 for RHEL/CentOS 7 - x86_64 - Source updates testing            disabled
pgdg13-updates-debuginfo/7/x86_64                   PostgreSQL 13 for RHEL/CentOS 7 - x86_64 - Debuginfo                         disabled
pgdg13-updates-testing/7/x86_64                     PostgreSQL 13 for RHEL/CentOS 7 - x86_64 - Updates testing                   disabled
pgdg13-updates-testing-debuginfo/7/x86_64           PostgreSQL 13 for RHEL/CentOS 7 - x86_64 - Debuginfo                         disabled
!pgdg94/7/x86_64                                    PostgreSQL 9.4 for RHEL/CentOS 7 - x86_64                                    disabled
pgdg94-source/7/x86_64                              PostgreSQL 9.4 for RHEL/CentOS 7 - x86_64 - Source                           disabled
pgdg95/7/x86_64                                     PostgreSQL 9.5 for RHEL/CentOS 7 - x86_64                                    enabled:    572
pgdg95-source/7/x86_64                              PostgreSQL 9.5 for RHEL/CentOS 7 - x86_64 - Source                           disabled
pgdg95-updates-debuginfo/7/x86_64                   PostgreSQL 9.5 for RHEL/CentOS 7 - x86_64 - Debuginfo                        disabled
pgdg96/7/x86_64                                     PostgreSQL 9.6 for RHEL/CentOS 7 - x86_64                                    enabled:    603
pgdg96-source/7/x86_64                              PostgreSQL 9.6 for RHEL/CentOS 7 - x86_64 - Source                           disabled
pgdg96-updates-debuginfo/7/x86_64                   PostgreSQL 9.6 for RHEL/CentOS 7 - x86_64 - Debuginfo                        disabled
updates/7/x86_64                                    CentOS-7 - Updates                                                           enabled:    245
updates-source/7                                    CentOS-7 - Updates Sources                                                   disabled
```

Comment: Do you get the same output from the `yum` command if your virtual environment is not activated?

Comment: That kernel version does not look like an up-to-date CentOS 7 install. I get `3.10.0-1062.18.1.el7.x86_64`. Are you using a custom kernel?

Comment: Hi @cherdt, I don't know -- this is the default as provided by unmanaged A2 hosting.

Comment: What is the output of `cat /etc/system-release`?

Comment: Hi @Cherdt, it is "CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003 (Core)"

Comment: It says in your output of `yum grouplist` that `Development Tools` is installed.

Comment: @NasirRiley is right. I get the same output from yum if Development Tools is already installed, i.e. `Maybe run: yum groups mark install (see man yum)
No packages in any requested group available to install or update`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your console output it says: `Maybe run: yum groups mark install (see man yum)`—did you do this?

Try running the following commands:

```
yum groups mark install "Development Tools"
yum groups mark convert "Development Tools"
yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
```

Reference: [RedHat Customer Portal discussion](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/1262603)

Comment: @AdminBee Thanks for the welcome! My post is the complete solution—I have run into the same issue previously, and the above commands do install "Development Tools". I will edit my post for clarity.

Comment: Hi @ThatsWhatSheCoded, I gave your solution a whirl (included output as an edit to my question), but sadly, no dice.

Comment: @Dave Would you please try running this command: `yum groupinstall "Development Tools" --setopt=group_package_types=mandatory,default,optional`. Additionally what is the output of the command `yum grouplist`?

Comment: Hi @ThatsWhatSheCoded, added both outputs as a second edit to my question.  Basically "No packages in any requested group available to install or update" and then the list you were interested in.

Comment: @Dave It looks like the groupinstall command worked — what is the output of the command `yum group update "Development Tools"`? Has it not downloaded/installed any of the associated binaries (e.g. `swig`, `bison`, `automake`)?

Comment: You know what, I think you're right.  I originally opened this question b/c I wasn't able to build a Python distribution (3.7).  I'll give that a whirl and see if the configure/make stuff finally works now.

Comment: @Dave Feel free to ping me if you run into further issues compiling `gcc` from source as I have had to do it a number of times on CentOS machines!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```bsh
yum group list
```

To see if yum can find the `Development Tools` under `Available Groups`.
If it fails, try:

```bsh
yum clean all
yum group list
```

And see if it can find it. If it still fails, you might not have the correct mirrors enabled to resolve it.

try the clean command again and then:

```bsh
yum --disablerepo=\* --enablerepo=base,updates group list
```

If you can find it. Great! Install with:

```bsh
yum --disablerepo=\* --enablerepo=base,updates groupinstall "Development Tools"
```

If not so, can you give us the output of:

```bsh
yum repolist all
```

EDIT:

Thank you for the output.

I found an [article](https://support.eapps.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/438/55/user-guide---installing-the-centos-development-tools-gcc-flex-etc) which state the following: "*To install the CentOS Development tools, you will need to be able to connect to your Virtual Server using SSH, and work as the root user.*"

Try switching to user "root" (if you don't know the root login credentials, you can try `sudo su`. sudo also might work but I see you already have tried that...) and running the above commands.

Lastly, you can try and enable these "sources" repos:

- CentOS-7 - Base Sources
- CentOS-7 - Extras Sources
- CentOS-7 - Updates Sources

And than running `yum update` followed by `groupinstall`.

Let me know if that doesn't work. Good luck!

Comment: Hi, Tried all your suggestions, but sadly, nothing doin', so included output of "yum repolist all" as an edit to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Check your mirror and make sure you have base, extras and updates.

```
[base]
name=CentOS-7 - Base

mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=$basearch&repo=os&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

[updates]
name=CentOS-7 - Updates

mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=$basearch&repo=updates&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/updates/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentO

[extras]
name=CentOS-7 - Extras

mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=$basearch&repo=extras&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also trying the same to isntall `Development Tools` for `CentOS 7` but couldn't make a way. Finally I did something alternative.

You can install the following, this also includes basic development tools and there is a high chance it will meet your need:

```
yum install devtoolset-9
scl enable devtoolset-9 bash
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69263518/6907424